# Current Location program in android not working

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, mapfragment, currentlocation

all i have simple android application for finding current location ,I have tried some code a sbelow,But its not working.It only shows my static markers only,It doesn't show my vurrent Location marker,So please suggest me for it:

**Main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**main.java**

```
package com.example.mapannotations;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
    static final LatLng PointA = new LatLng(23.063905, 72.549629);
    static final LatLng PointB = new LatLng(23.043652, 72.528048);
    static final LatLng PointC = new LatLng(23.008738, 72.561865);
    static final LatLng PointD = new LatLng(23.007158, 72.493887);
    static final LatLng PointE = new LatLng(22.961644, 72.427111);
    private GoogleMap map;
    protected LocationListener locationListener;
    protected Context context;
    protected String latitude, longitude;
    protected boolean gps_enabled, network_enabled;

    public LocationManager loc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        // .getMap();
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        // FOR CURRENT LOCATION....
        loc = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        loc.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        // MAP MARKERS
        Marker sha = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(PointA)
                .title("ShastriNagar BRTS").snippet("BRTS Stop"));
        Marker nar = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(PointB)
                .title("Laldarwaja").snippet("Laldarwaja AMTS Bus Depot"));
        Marker pal = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(PointC)
                .title("Paldi").snippet("Paldi Bus Stop"));
        Marker Kar = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(PointD)
                .title("Karnavati Club")
                .snippet("Karnavati club- Enjoyment centre"));
        Marker jiv = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(PointE).title(
                "Jirvaraj Park"));

        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(PointA, 12));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // current Location marker

        Marker cur = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                .title("My current Location"));

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Latitude", "disable");

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Latitude", "enable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Latitude", "status");
    }

}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapannotations.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Please help me...thank you

Comment: Show your permissions in Manifest file. Have you took permission for FINE_LOCATION ?

Comment: i just have posted my manifest permissions in my question..please see it sir

Comment: Permissions are fine, Check your code under open sky. So GPS may have a clear signal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the gps may take a while to start. You could try

```
String mBestProvider = loc.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
loc.requestLocationUpdates(mBestProvider, 0, 0, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the old way of getting location updates with the new way you have to implement if you use Google Maps v2 for Android and the Location API.

My suggestion is to follow this official tutorial of the new Location API: https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

As you can see, you don't have to use a `LocationManager` instance to ask for updates, but `LocationRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. The GPS is tricky here. If you've set it to find your location, you have to make sure that your GPS is on. That means that it probably wont work on your emulator. Also, even if the GPS is on, it is still tricky because sometimes, it takes a lot of time for the GPS to find your location.